# What anti-keylogging programs can you use when using public PCs

Tags: security, encryption, malware, privacy

Are there anti-keylogging programs that can keep you safe while you are using a public PC terminal? Do they exist and what are these? I like to know that I am safe when entering data on a public PC for example from malware or keyloggers, who knows where it has been. Or else, how can I keep my personal data safe when using a public PC?

I think this question is relevant for anyone who is concerned about their security on any level.

Comment: In all honesty.... you can't. Don't use public terminals. There is no way to know what viruses, malware, rootkits, keyloggers, or mouse/screen recorders are installed. There's no way to know if the host is snooping on the network packets either. Never enter or view private data on a public terminal, and always use HTTPS or encryption when using public Wifi.

Comment: Theoretically, if there is an opportunity to insert network device a public terminal, your  protected  laptop can use protected network protocol and connect to protected server. Cloak tent that will hide you, monitor, keyboard, and your actions and will have elements of anti sniper protection. Also a good idea to take a set of stun grenades and install a smoke screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use/install an anti-keylogger program, that means that someone else can install a rootkit as well. You can try to install or startup a virtual keyboard or some other tool and see if that works. If so, the machine is probably not safe to start with. It's probably safer to use one that you can't mess with.

Take your own laptop, ipad, smartphone, and use wifi at a local bar. Use https-everywhere if possible, or set gmail, facebook etc to use https only. Use VPN if you're really worried.

---

NB: I can imagine that a machine is not safe and you can mess with it. Someone uses it and then the session is closed. If the machine is reset back to a clean snapshot after each closed session, it might be relatively safe, in the sense that if you stay away from unsafe sites, you'll probably stay clean. So if it appears to work like that, you can start a new session, browse facebook, hotmail, gmail, and stay safe. Then you start a new session, browse whatever unsafe site you want, don't login to gmail etc....

Answer (score 0):

you can look at something like this:
http://download.cnet.com/Anti-Keylogger-Virtual-Keyboard/3000-2144_4-75157374.html or 
http://free-anti-keylogger.com/

but there is no guarantee you will be able to execute it on the pc (depends on system rights).

bear in mind Darth Android cautions. they are quite right, there is no expectation of privacy on a public machine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the way may be:
[Live_CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) or the same Live_USB system. But, anyway, there is a chance that PC "upgraded" with [hardware keylogger](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/homemade-hardware-keylogger-phukd).

You should check PS/2 or usb connector of keyboard before use live system.

Such hardware keylogger may be bought for a little cost: _www.amecisco.com.

Looking forward, there are million places to hide hardware keylogger from user on public PC. That is why any public PC should not be counted like a trusted system.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to at least secure your logins info use a password manager like lastpass 
log into your vault using one time password or the virtual keyboard (on screen)
after that you just let lastpass log you in websites

Comment: Doing what you describe does not prevent a keylogger from capturing your passwords. Keyloggers often have the ability to take screenshots and access your clipboard. Accessing your lastpass account on an unprotected unknown computer is a horrible idea.  The only time I trust a public computer is one that makes is crystal clear private data is removed such as a kisok.

Comment: even if a keylogger capture the passord it's a one time passord good for only one use

and lastpass dont use the clipboard to fill in passwords 
and snapshots wont be effective as well

Comment: @MartinHoulie - You have to setup LastPass to accept OTP it does not by default.  If you are using OTP then you have little to fear, using OTP, is for untrusted computers.  The screenshot comment was with regards to virtual keyboards, useless, as far as I am concerned.